# Using Audacity to speed up pauses and repetitive/monotonous sounds

Tags: audio, script, audacity

I record some kind of podcast with Audacity, and I have to deal with annoying post-processing where I have to remove pauses from recording - all kinds of sighs, *umms* and silent search for words.

I would appreciate the following effect: find all places where the signal does not change a lot, and speed them up without changing tone to the same extent as their relative change speed. This means all pauses are eliminated, all sighs are shortened and *ummmms* are turned into *ums*.

I wonder if there is any existing tool (Audacity itself, some kind of script or plugin or any other tool) that allows doing that.

I think there was a tool like this for images (it removed boring parts) but I'm not so sure about sounds.

Comment: You could try to use "Truncate silence". You can set a threshold in decibels and then set the action to "compress" instead of "truncate" so it will speed it up instead of removing it. I'm not sure if this "compress" option works well. I only used truncate myself to completely remove silences. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Shifty I did not know that this function actually has compression instead of outright removal! Can you convert that to answer so I can accept it? At -30dB threshold it works reasonably well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use "Truncate silence". You can set a threshold in decibels and then set the action to "compress" instead of "truncate" so it will speed it up instead of removing it. I'm not sure if this "compress" option works well. I only used truncate myself to completely remove silences. Hope this helps!